# "Will have to for five minutes" vs "have to for five minutes"

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

If I want to say I (must) turn off my camera right now {it is urgent} and this action is going to last for five minutes, do I say

I'll have to turn off my camera for five minutes.
or
I have to turn off my camera for five minutes.

As much as I remember from my grammar classes a billion years ago, the first one should be used for future actions (I'll have to turn off my camera for five minutes [unspecified time in the future]) while the second one implies I have to do it right now.

Although then the same thing happens with these two sentences and I'm not entirely sure what the difference is, which is what confused me in the first place

I'll be taking this or
I'm taking this

[this laptop, for example, when you take it away from somebody]

Comment: I don't think anyone would find it odd if you used the first one to mean that you were about to turn it off.

Comment: People are just as likely to say ***I'll be** off now* as ***I'm** off now* when they're leaving. But they can also say ***I'm going tomorrow*** with the same meaning as ***I will** go tomorrow*. Anglophones are often pretty flexible / relaxed about verb tenses.